# python - comparing 2 dictionaries and print the non equal values

Tags: dictionary

I am newbie to Python.
I have 2 dictionaries which have the same keys but some keys have different values.
I would like to Iterate over the first dictionary and find the equal key In the second dictionary, check to see If the values equal and If not then print both values.
Can someone please help me with a template I can use?
Thanks

Comment: 10x a bunch, It works :)

Comment: Great! can you select my answer as correct?

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over one and compare the values.

```
dict2 = {"key1":"value1",
         "key2":"value3"}
dict1 = {"key1":"value1",
         "key2":"value2"}
for key in dict1:
    if dict1[key] != dict2[key]:
           print(key,dict1[key],dict2[key])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dict1 = {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value4"}
dict2 = {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value3"}

for key, value1 in dict1.items():
    try:
        value2 = dict2[key]

        if value1 != value2:
            print(key, value1, value2)
    except KeyError:
        print(key, value1, None)
```